# Canonical Representation of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. 
Every simple function $g_N$ can be in a unique (canonical) way
$$
f_N=\sum_{k=}^N a_k 1_{A_k}
$$
with $a_k> 0$ and $A_k\in \mathcal{F}$ mutually disjoint.

Any positive function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the limit of a (nonunique) sequence of simple functions $(g_N)$.

My questions is:
Is the sequence of simple functions $f_N$ with 
$$
f_N \rightarrow f
$$
unique, when represented in the canonical way?

Comment: I don't really understand. You are saying yourself that the sequence is **not** unique. The representation of these functions is not relevant: it will not change the sequence. Btw, I would say "non-negative" instead of "positive". The zero function is also a simple function. You can write it as $1_{\varnothing}$.

Comment: $g_N$ is not unique and $f_N$ is unique.

Comment: "(nonunique) sequence of simple functions $(g_N)$" Don't you mean "sequence of (nonunique) simple functions $(g_N)$" then? Also you must make a distinction between "function" and "representation of function". One function can have multiple representations, and in this case one of these representations "jumps out" and gets the label "canonical". There are several distinct sequences of simple functions that converge to $f$. Then automatically the sequences of their canonical representations are distinct too.